# Duplicate rows according to a function of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My initial example dataframe is in the following format:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {'n': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
         'initial': [3, 4, 10, 10],
         'final': [3, 7, 11, 7],}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
       n  initial  final
0    one        3      3
1    two        4      7
2  three       10     11
3   four       10      7
```

What I hope to achieve is to duplicate the values in the `n` column a number of times corresponding to the values between those in the `initial` and `final` columns.

For example, in the first row, `initial` and `final` hold the same value, so there should be one instance of `'one'` in the output dataframe's `n` column. For the second row, `initial` and `final` are three numbers apart, so there should be four repetitions of `'two'`, and so on. If `final` is less than `initial`, there should be no instances of the value in `n` in the output.

There should also be a `count` column which counts up from the value in the `initial` column to the value in the `final` column. My expected output is as follows:

```
       n  count
0    one      3
1    two      4
2    two      5
3    two      6
4    two      7
5  three     10
6  three     11
```

I've tried using `reindex` with a new index based on `df.final - df.initial + 1`, but this does not handle the negative values as in the fourth row of the example dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case create the `list` with range then `explode`

```
# in order to save running time , df = df.query('initial<=final')
df['count'] = [ range(x, y + 1) for x, y in zip(df['initial'], df['final'])]
out = df.explode('count').dropna()
Out[13]: 
       n  initial  final count
0    one        3      3     3
1    two        4      7     4
1    two        4      7     5
1    two        4      7     6
1    two        4      7     7
2  three       10     11    10
2  three       10     11    11
```

Comment: @ScottBoston Happy holidays, my friend ~

Answer (score 2):

```
out = (df[['n']].join(df.apply(lambda x: range(x[1], x[2] + 1), axis=1)
                      .explode().to_frame('count'))
       .dropna(subset=['count']))
```

`out`

```
      n  count
0    one      3
1    two      4
2    two      5
3    two      6
4    two      7
5  three     10
6  three     11
```